# PMI client SOAP error

Tags: java, soap, websphere

I have been trying to create a JAVA PMI Client for remote monitoring of the IBM WebSphere Application server(v 6.0).
The points to condider prior to any discussions are:
1. Security has been enabled under global security.
2. I am using IBM java hopefully(downloaded the trail client from IBM).
3. Copied the certificates from remote server to my local PMI client location.
4. Ports connectivity checked.

The problem:
When trying to create the connection the error returned is:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/ibm/ws/management/AdminHelper.getPlatformHelper()Lcom/ibm/ws/util/PlatformHelper;
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.setupSslSetting(SOAPConnectorClient.java:1103)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.access$100(SOAPConnectorClient.java:94)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient$1.run(SOAPConnectorClient.java:249)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.(SOAPConnectorClient.java:188)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Kunal Soni

Comment: Gobal security shows "enable" checked but the "soap.client.props" says disabled.  Please let me know if it should proceed with security enabled at my client or disabled?

Comment: Looks like you have version mismatch. Your client runtime is different than your server runtime.

Comment: Ok i have checked the Client runtime is version 7 and the Server version i am trying to connect is version 6.

Comment: Yes the server runtime i am using is version 7 and the Server version tried to connect is version 6. I thought there must be backward compatibility. Lets check . Thanks

Comment: Adding some more jars in the classpath helped to come to another exception of ClassNotFound. Could someone please suggest if we know the jar file containing "com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.LoggingServices"?

Comment: It will be better if you install same runtime for client (v6) as the server, rather than trying to make v7 connect to v6. Install WAS v6 on your client machine and use java provided with that. Or just use IBM Health Center for monitoring, maybe it will have all the features you need.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to connect to WebSphere is to use the WebSphere Application Client that comes with WebSphere itself as a separate download.

It's free to use when connecting to a remote WebSphere Application Server installation.

Also when starting your program make sure you add this parameter to the JVM arguments: -Dwas.install.root=WAS_APP_CLIENT_HOME (example: -Dwas.install.root=/opt/WebSphere6/AppClient)

I'm using WebSphere App Client version 6 for many years to connect to WebSphere 6, 7 and 8 without any issues.

Hope this helps !

Richard Levac

[WasMonitor - WebSphere Data Collector and More !](http://wasmonitor.com)